# How do i sort data attributes in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying with the use of jquery to sort the person, color and opinion based on data attributes.

What info i would like to get from each is

Person | Color | Opinion

So expected result would be for example this.

James | Blue | Looks good

Rebecka | Black | Looks very bad

```js
    let firstPerson = $('ul').first().data('person');
    let lastPerson = $('ul:last').data('person');
    let firstPersonColors = $().children('li').attr('color_opinion');
    
    let test = $("ul").find(`[data-person='${lastPerson}']`);
    
    console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <ul data-person="James">
    <li data-color_opinion="blue">Looks good</li>
    <li data-color_opinion="green">Looks ok</li> 
    </ul>

    <ul data-person="Rebecka">
    <li data-color_opinion="blue">Looks bad</li> 
    <li data-color_opinion="black">Looks very bad</li>
    </ul> 

    </div>
```

Comment: You haven't defined sort criteria or a specific problem and haven't provided expected results. Please take a few minutes to read [ask]

Comment: You need a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate both lists and then their children using jQuery Each method.
If you want a table, you can append the result to html table.

```js
    $.each($('ul'), function(i, el){

       $.each($(el).find("[data-color_opinion]"), function(j, child){

          console.log($(el).data('person'), "|", $(child).data('color_opinion'), "|", $(child).text())
       });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <ul data-person="James">
    <li data-color_opinion="blue">Looks good</li>
    <li data-color_opinion="green">Looks ok</li> 
    </ul>

    <ul data-person="Rebecka">
    <li data-color_opinion="blue">Looks bad</li> 
    <li data-color_opinion="black">Looks very bad</li>
    </ul> 

    </div>
```